# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file opencv_gpu249d.lib

Tags: opencv, cuda, visual-studio-2013, gpu

I'm trying build opencv for use with CUDA from sources, I'm currently using sources from 2.4.9 prebuilt setup as git is very slow.

I use Visual Studio 2013 and Cuda 6.5
First there was many errors like cannot find `opencv_core249d.lib` etc, so I added `prebuilt` libraries to the path variable, and these errors are gone now except one error. It looks for `opencv_gpu249d.lib` inside `lib/Debug`, why is it looking for this `opencv_gpu249d.lib` when its not compiled yet?
why isn't it using the `gpu249d.lib` inside `prebuilt` libraries?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure it even exists ? previous versions did not come with any gpu support for the prebuilt libs.

Comment: Yes, its here, 
OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu249d

Comment: just saying, if you got the sources, it might be wise to build *everything* from scratch. at least you know, that the parts fit.

Comment: How to build from scratch? It gives errors because it's dependent on the libraries that not are not compiled yet. I'm not expert in compiling from source. I need to compile opencv in Windows for use with CUDA.

Comment: hint: you should not add them to path variable but to the project setting: "additional link directories" (but should make no difference about your problem though)

Comment: compile from source: install CMake and open openCV cmake project. It's quite simple to compile with CMake. Check all those CUDA settings within CMake.

Comment: If i install CMake in windows , is it same as install opencv using  CMake in Linux? Can the binaries built by CMake , use with Visual Studio also?

Comment: I used CMake to make project files for Visual Studio using "Visual Studio C++ compilers" . Which compiler should i use now ?

Comment: yes, create the solution file for your visual studio version and compiler. It should be the visual c++ compiler. Which ones can you choose?

Comment: I choose like following for Visual studio 2013 64bit
VC/bin/cl.exe

And I can select the packages I want, what to do next ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [great wiki tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation)!.

For Compiling with cuda please select Advanced Check box in `CMAKE` & In `Cuda` module `uncheck` the `CUDA_ATTACH_VS_BUILD_RULE_TO_CUDA_FILE flag`. Now compile & enjoy.
[image]

Comment: I have already deselected Cuda_ATTACH_VS.......
I still have the problem with compiler trying to look for opencv_gpu298d.lib inside lib/debug folder

Comment: Have you build the source code through VS? Or you just copied it to that folder?

Comment: If you mean the lib files, I made my path variable to point to lib files in prebuilt lib files, because VS generates many errors if it can't find the lib files, I don't know why it needs the prebuilt lib files.

Comment: Please follow the steps correctly as mentioned in the wiki tutor. otherwise you will face many error.

Comment: I have followed the same steps but I dont know why the wiki tutor  doesn't face the same problem. Same steps up to build debug. But it  gives many linking errors unable to find the lib files such as opencv_core249d.lib . That's why I set path variable to point to prebuilt lib files. Now It doesn't say error about core249.lib, But it still gives an error cannot open gpu249d.lib

Answer (score 0):

The pre-compiled OpenCV libraries does not support CUDA. You have to compile them again with CUDA enabled. I tried a lot times before I managed to build OpenCV 2.4.9 + CUDA 6.5 + vs2013 from the source.

In short you need to cancel ‘CUDA_ATTACH_VS_BUILD_RULE_TO_CUDA_FILE’, and enable ‘WITH_CUBLAS’, ‘WITH_CUDA’, ‘WITH_OPENGL’, ‘WITH_TBB’.

Detailed steps can be found here: [OPENCV 2.4.9 + CUDA 6.5 + VISUAL STUDIO 2013](http://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/)

TBB and Python are possibly unnecessary, but I am not sure. I have both of them. The compiled *opencv_gpu249d.lib* works fine for me.